# Warning: Attempt to present <AdjustPhotoViewController> on <TakePhotoViewController> while a presentation is in progress

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, overlay-view

I am using xcode 4.5.2 and created my own OverlayViewController for camera buttons.

Now, when my delegate controller - TakePhotoViewController retrieves the didFinishWithCamera action from OverlayViewController, I would like to transfer the user to AdjustPhotoViewController.

However, I get the following warning and it is not being transferred:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on
>    while a presentation is in progress!

```
- (void)didFinishWithCamera
{
    [[self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromTakeToAdjust" sender:self];    
}
```

Comment: Give some time between old transition or just dismiss it with Animation `NO`

Comment: The Animation: No does not help. What do you mean by give some time?

Comment: "Give some time between old transition" - this is completely wrong approach. See my answer.

Comment: @Stas not only that it's incorrect, it also does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in TakePhotoViewController, I had :

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [self openImagePicker];
}
```

This caused to open the image picker, while trying to close it at the same time.

I added a flag to check it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, in my experience, this is to do with calling a segue and an IBAction (that calls a segue) from the same button - check the connections inspector in Interface Builder to see if your button is connected to both.

In your storyboard, it may look like this:

[image]

In your code, it may look like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushToNewVC"]) {
        UIViewController *controller = (UIViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}

=

- (IBAction)launchNew VC:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushToNewVC" sender:sender];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to give time for old transition to finish and new transition to come

usually `0.3` works but adjust it as per your need

```
- (void)didFinishWithCamera
{
    [[self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self performSelector:@selector(showModel) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
}

- (void)showModel {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromTakeToAdjust" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Still. It's probably something deeper

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following code for the overlay viewcontroller.

please verify with you code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  
    [self.window addSubview:self.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

In  viewdidload event following code use

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;

    self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    self.picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    // Insert the overlay
    self.overlay = [[Customview alloc] initWithNibName:@"Customview" bundle:nil];
    self.overlay.pickerRef = self.picker;
    self.picker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlay.view;

    [self presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:NO];
}
```

In view .h method following code use

```
   @interface CameraController : UIViewController {
        UIImagePickerController* __picker;
        Customview* __overlay;
    }

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImagePickerController* picker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Customview* overlay;
```

Hope above code may help to you.

Comment: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions - where shall I add this method? and what is navigationController

Comment: did you use navigation controller in your application?

Comment: I have 3 views: TakePhoto which is a delegate of OverlayViewController and AdjustPhoto. What doy ou mean by navigation controller?

Comment: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions -where shall I add it?

Comment: if you still get trouble then inform to me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21208/discussion-between-odelya-and-neon-samuel)

Answer (score 1):

Odelya, you should perform all actions with UI that meant to be performed AFTER some animation (in this cae controller dismissal) in the completion block! It actually is created for these purposes. Edit your code like this:

```
- (void)didFinishWithCamera
{
    if(![[self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController presentingViewController] isBeingDismissed]) {
        [[self.overlayViewController.imagePickerController presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^ {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fromTakeToAdjust" sender:self];
        }];
    }   
}
```

EDIT:I've added the if statement, try it now.

Comment: I get Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIImagePickerController>

Comment: Still. same problem. It seems to me that the picker is not being dismissed somehow

Comment: I think that the problem is not in this code. Let us know if you'll solve the problem!